# Problems while trying to extract keys and values from a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, data-structures, list-comprehension

I have a nested dictionary with the following structure:

```
{

    status: {3 items},
    entity_list: [],
    concept_list: [
        {6 items},
        {7 items},
        {7 items},
        {7 items},
        {6 items},
        {6 items},
        {7 items},
        {7 items},
        {6 items}
    ],
    time_expression_list: [],
    money_expression_list: [],
    quantity_expression_list: [1 item],
    other_expression_list: [],
    quotation_list: [],
    relation_list: [10 items]

}
```

Let's focus in `concept_list` (note that I omitted irrelevant information just for visualization purposes):

```
concept_list: [

    {
        form: "length",
        id: "566859a9e3",
        sementity: {
            class: "class",
            fiction: "nonfiction",
            id: "A",
            type: "None"
        },
        semld_list: [1 item],
        variant_list: [2 items],
        relevance: "100"
    },
    {
        form: "length",
        id: "f06dc65ae1",
        sementity: {
            class: "class",
            fiction: "nonfiction",
            id: "B",
            type: "None"
        },
        semld_list: [1 item],
        semtheme_list: [
            {
                id: "C",
                type: "None"
            }
        ],
        variant_list: [2 items],
        relevance: "100"
    },
    {7 items},
    {7 items},
    {6 items},
    {6 items},
    {7 items},
    {7 items},
    {6 items},
    {6 items},
    {7 items},
    {7 items},
    {6 items},
    {6 items},
    {6 items}
]
```

In general, from the `content_list` key, How can I extract into a new dict `sementity`'s and `semtheme_list`'s `id`s values (if they exist)?. For instance, the new dictionary should have this structure `(*)`:

```
new_dict = {

    {  'form: 'length',
       'sementity':'A',
      'semtheme_list':'NaN'
    }
    ,
    { 'form: 'length',
      'sementity':'B',
      'semtheme_list':'C'
    }
    ,
    ...
}
```

Also, if the element doesn't exist I would like to add a `NaN` value. So far, I tried to use [mdict](https://github.com/rikonor/mdict):

```
from mdict import MDict
for item in a_dict:
    a = MDict(item)
print(a.get('concept_list:id'))
```

And

```
for t in a_dict:
    #print(t)
    if 'concept_list' in t:
        myvalues = [i['concept_list'] for i in t if 'concept_list' in i]
        print(myvalues)
```

However i do not get the values in a dict like `(*)`.

Comment: Your data is a JSON formatted string, not a valid Python dict/list structure.

Comment: A dict has key, value pairs.  You're constructing it more like a set.  How do you want your final result to look?

Comment: Like `(*)` (i.e.`{ 'sementity':'A',
      'semtheme_list':'NaN'
    }
    ,
    {
      'sementity':'B',
      'semtheme_list':'C'
    }
    ,
    ...
}`)

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  If you're looking for a complex list comprehension, you could do something like this: `[{'sementity': item.get('sementity', {}).get('id'), 'semtheme_list': next(iter(item.get('semtheme_list', [])), {}).get('id')} for item in original['concept_list']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your list of 'sementities' by looping through your `concept_entry` value like:

```
new_list = []
for s in data["concept_list"]:
    new_list.append({
        "sementity": s["sementity"]["id"],
        "semtheme_list": s["semtheme_list"][0]["id"] if "semtheme_list" in s else "NaN"
    })
```

Or if you prefer everything in one step:

```
new_list = [{"sementity": s["sementity"]["id"],
             "semtheme_list": s["semtheme_list"][0]["id"]
             if "semtheme_list" in s else "NaN"} for s in data["concept_list"]]
```

But that will not give you your `new_dict` structure because that would be an invalid structure in Python. It will instead contain a list of extracted values. Of course, I'd strongly encourage you to add some validation before parsing everything like this unless you're sure that your data is always as you've presented it.

Also, I haven't the faintest idea on what you mean under "*values in a dict like `(*)`*"

Comment: What I meant to say was that `(*)` denotes the expected output example

Comment: @tumbleweed - you said that you've already converted your JSON to a Python `dict` structure - if you didn't, before looping through it make sure you've parsed it (i.e. `data = json.loads(your_json)`)

Comment: Yes, OK Now its a dict!... Thanks!.. I thought you wanted to consider the json as a json, instead of a dict

Comment: I also forgot to mention I would like to extract the form, and add it to the final dict, the problem is that the form is outside.. how can I do that?, I tried to : `"form": s["form"]` is that accurate?...

Comment: @tumbleweed - yep, you can add any data available to your loop to the resulting `dict` - `"form": s["form"]` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help @zwer

Answer (score 1):

Here a way to do that, with more generic labels:

```
from pylab import *

data={ randint(10):{randint(10):randint(10) for i in range(3)} for i in range(3)}
# {1: {0: 1, 1: 4, 8: 6}, 2: {4: 8, 6: 8, 9: 4}, 5: {1: 7, 3: 1, 9: 2}}

extraction = [ {k:(d[k] if k in d else NaN) for k in (0,1)} for d in data.values()]
# [{0: 1, 1: 4}, {0: nan, 1: nan}, {0: nan, 1: 7}]
```

I guess `extraction` must be a list, not a dict.